# mod_rewrite: Rewrite URL to point to cgi script, but keep rewrite hidden

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the URL

```
http://domain.com/whatever
```

To:

```
http://domain.com/cgi-bin/script.cgi
```

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /whatever /cgi-bin/script.cgi [NC]
```

This doesn't work and gives me a 404 error. However, this works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /whatever http://domain.com/cgi-bin/script.cgi [NC]
```

But in that case, the URL change is vivible to the user. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have other rules? Also there's no leading slash for the rewrite rule's pattern (the URI used for matching has leading slashes removed)

Comment: No other rules. Those are the complete contents of the .htaccess file. I'm not sure what you mean about the leading slahes, but the second example works to perform the redirect, so I don't believe it's an issue with the pattern...

Comment: Edited: never mind, I was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the `[PT]` flag fixed it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /whatever /cgi-bin/script.cgi [NC,PT]
```

Now if somebody could just explain why that's needed and what is actually going on, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: `passthrough|PT` - Forces the resulting URI to be passed back to the URL mapping engine for processing of other URI-to-filename translators, such as Alias or Redirect. The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be treated as a URI instead. That is to say, the use of the [PT] flag causes the result of the RewriteRule to be passed back through URL mapping, so that location-based mappings, such as Alias, Redirect, or ScriptAlias, for example, might have a chance to take effect.

Comment: If, for example, you have an Alias for /icons, and have a RewriteRule pointing there, you should use the [PT] flag to ensure that the Alias is evaluated. Omission of the [PT] flag in this case will cause the Alias to be ignored, resulting in a 'File not found' error being returned.

Comment: So probably you had some redirects or aliases which should have been applied to the rewritten URL?

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem with a non PHP CGI by using the apache rewrite engine.
Everything works fine but the query string was not added...

To solve it you has to set the "QSA" parameter in the rewrite config

```
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
AddHandler cgi-script .vbs .wsf .rex .bat .cmd .bas .rexg
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

#Require local

RewriteEngine   on

#RewriteRule "(.*\.vbs)$" "/cgi/test.rex"
#[H=cgi-script]
# AVOID RECURSION BY CONDITION !!!
RewriteCond  "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!(.*)/cgi\.rex" 
RewriteRule "(.*\.rex)$" "/cgi/cgi.rex?$1" [NC,PT,QSA]
RewriteRule "(.*\.vbs)$" "/cgi/cgi.rex?$1" [NC,PT,QSA]
RewriteRule "(.*\.rsp)$" "/cgi/cgi.rex?$1" [NC,PT,QSA]



#RewriteLog      "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 2



</Directory>
```

After this changes the query string environment was back :)